# Google Maps - Trigger Search Box on button click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm interested in implementing a Google Maps search button with a 'Submit'/'Go' button next to it (such as on http://maps.google.com). Everything works great if I press Enter in the search box, but I have no idea how to force/submit the search using the button.

Right now I have my code based on the example on: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox . The most important part is that I'm using this for now:

HTML:

```
<div id="intro-search">
    <input id="search-box" />
    <button type="button">Submit!</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    // ... 
    // Show the results on the map
    // ...
  }
```

I have no idea how to trigger the same thing on a button click.

On another note, what is the difference between the [SearchBox](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#SearchBox) and the [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete) controls? Don't they do the same thing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the SearchBox, you have to use google map's trigger event on the input field like so

```
document.getElementById('my-button').onclick = function () {
    var input = document.getElementById('my-input');

    google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'focus', {});
    google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'keydown', { keyCode: 13 });
    google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'focus', {});

};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I have looking for! And it works even in IE11!

Comment: not working in my case i'm using on edit page. will this work on console window

Answer (score 5):

To build on Alex Beauchemin's and Scott Butler's answers, a non-Angular, non-jQuery option that works for me today (but may not in the future) is:

```
document.getElementById('my-button').onclick = function () {
  var input = document.getElementById('my-input');

  function noop() {}

  google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'focus', {});
  google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'keydown', {
    keyCode: 40, // arrow down
    stopPropagation: noop, // because these get called
    preventDefault: noop,
  });  
  google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'keydown', { keyCode: 13 });  // enter
  google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'focus', {});
};
```

Comment: This worked! What I was missing was the weird empty function there. Would you care to explain me what that's doing?

Comment: So the stopPropagation and preventDefault fields are expecting functions that will be called, so something needs to go there. In my case, I didn't need to do anything, so I put a function there that doesn't do anything (a [no-op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) function). Leaving it out, or null, caused an error.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd share this in case someone finds this thread as I did.  This seemed to work for me.  This is a directive I made.  So i on your input, you can use

```
<input id="txtLocation" places-auto-complete autocomplete-select-first-on-enter>
```

.

```
app.directive('autocompleteSelectFirstOnEnter', function() {
    //Requires jquery.simulate
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown", function(e) {
            if(e.which === 40){
                //if they already clicked down, we don't want to click down again
                element.triggered = true;
            }
            if(e.which === 13 && !element.triggered) {
                //They clicked enter, and haven't clicked down yet, and its not recursive
                element.triggered = true; //keep it from being recursive
                $("input#" + element[0].id).trigger('focus');
                $("input#" + element[0].id).simulate('keydown', { keyCode: 40 } ).simulate('keydown', { keyCode: 13 });
                element.triggered = false; //reset it
            }
        });
        element.bind("focus", function(e) {
            //reset it when they click in the field
            element.triggered = false;
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a click listener for your button inside the `initialize` function.

Something like :

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").onclick = function(){
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
}
```

With that you have access to the searchbox object exactly like in the `places_changed` listener of the searchbox.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem is that getPlaces() returns 'Undefined'. Apparently, it doesn't necessary get the places without 'Enter'?

Comment: Or maybe because, before the `click` event, the input loses focus and the dropdown with the results (and the results themselves) disappears.

Comment: If you want to force users to use the button, you will have to remove the `places_changed` listener of the searchbox, that way clicking on one of the options of the dropdown list (or hitting enter) wont trigger the event and change the map. You have to make sure that the searchbox has a value.

Answer (score -1):

You need add a event listener, for example:

```
destiny =  new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('textfield'));
destiny.addListener("places_changed",function(){
            alert("You have selected something");
        });
```

When the user select a text-location, the alert will be fired.

Comment: The question is about using a submit button, the event 'places_changed' doesn't work when the input is out of focus